# Fiber product of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $f: X \longrightarrow S$ and $g: Y \longrightarrow S$ be two $S$-schemes. Then, one can form the fiber product $X \times_S Y$. My question is: Is there always a morphism of schemes $Y \longrightarrow_S X \times Y$ or $X \longrightarrow X \times_S Y$?

If we restrict ourselves to the affine case, say $X=Spec A$, $Y= Spec B$ and $S= Spec R$, then one can form a morphism from $A \longrightarrow A \otimes_R B$ obviously. Is gluing these affines change anything?

Comment: You need $A\otimes_RB\to A$. And the statement is false. Let $X,Y$ be two disjoint open subschemes of $S$ with $f,g$ respective inclusions.

Comment: @JWL this seems like an answer to me - would you care to record it below?

Comment: In the affine case you can take $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and $A$ and $B$ to be two rings of different nonzero characteristics, say $A = \mathbb{F}_2, B = \mathbb{F}_3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Copied from my comment)

What you need is $A\otimes_RB\to A$, and the statement is false. Let $X,Y$ be two disjoint nonempty open subschemes of $S$. Then the fibered product is empty so there is no morphism into it.